# What is the efficient way to update value inside Spark's RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm writing a graph-related program in `Scala` with `Spark`. The dataset have 4 million nodes and 4 million edges(you can treat this as a tree), but for each time(an `Iteration`), I only edit a portion of it, namely a sub-tree rooted by a given node, and the nodes in a path between that given node and root.

The `Iteration` has dependency, which means `i+1` `Iteration` needs the result coming from `i`. So I need store the result of each `Iteration` for next step.

I'm trying to find an efficient way to update `RDD`, but have no clue so far.I find that `PairRDD` have a `lookup` function which could reduce the computation time from `O(N)`, to O(`M`), `N` denote the total number of objects in `RDD` and `M` denote the number of elements in each partition.

So I'm thinking is there anyway that I could update an object in the `RDD` with `O(M)`? Or more ideally, O(1)?(I see an email in Spark's mail list saying that the `lookup` can be modified to achieve O(1))

Another thing is, if I could achieve `O(M)` for updating the `RDD`, could I increase the partition to some number larger than the number of cores I have and achieve a better performance?

Comment: RDD is immutable, you can only create a new RDD by transformation but can't update it.

Comment: @cloud Thanks for your comment, does that mean I need to create a whole new RDD instead of only a partition?

Comment: That's it. I will write an answer to explain it in detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An RDD is a distributed data set, a partition is the unit for RDD storage, and the unit to process and RDD is an element.

For example, you read a large file from HDFS as an RDD, then the element of this RDD is `String`(lines in that file), and spark stores this RDD across the cluster by partition. For you, as a spark user, you only need to care about how to deal with the lines of that files, just like you are writing a normal program, and you read a file from local file system line by line. That's the power of spark:)

Anyway, you have no idea which elements will be stored in a certain partition, so it doesn't make sense  to update a certain partition.

Comment: So based on your and maasg's answer, I should treat RDD as a normal object and do not trying to "tuning" the performance on the lower level, since the framework will do that for me and creating a new RDD with object reusing(so basically the creation just an iteration and replace some object with new ones) is not as slow as I thought?

Comment: @bxshi RDD object is cheap, but the data inside it is expensive. For example, you write an application: data_source -> rdd1 -> rdd2 -> rdd3 -> get_result. What spark do actually is: remember your transformation t1, t2, t3, and apply these transformation to data source and get result. Spark won't keep the data of RDD unless you call `RDD.cache()`.

Comment: @cloud : Does it mean , only one RDD will exist at any given time?

Comment: @cloud why i am asking this is , if we have multiple RDD's it will take more disk space / memory..right?

Answer (score 6):

As functional data structures, RDDs are immutable and an operation on an RDD generates a new RDD.

Immutability of the structure does not necessarily mean full replication. Persistant data structures are a common functional pattern where operations on immutable structures yield a new structure but previous versions are maintained and often reused.

GraphX (a 'module' on top of Spark) is a graph API on top of Spark that uses such concept: From the docs:

> Changes to the values or structure of the graph are accomplished by
>   producing a new graph with the desired changes. Note that substantial
>   parts of the original graph (i.e., unaffected structure, attributes,
>   and indicies) are reused in the new graph reducing the cost of this
>   inherently functional data-structure.

It might be a solution for the problem at hand: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/graphx-programming-guide.html

Comment: Yes they are reused, but you still need to iterate through all the elements to create the new object.

Comment: When you say "I'm trying to find an efficient way to update RDD" I though you were referring to on-site mutations. Are you rather talking about lookup?

Comment: @massg Well I did want to talk about update RDD but I made a mistake about the definition of `iteration`. When you do a map or other manipulation operations to create a new RDD, you do have parallelism on such operations but you still need to access all the elements inside the old RDD.

Comment: @bxshi Indeed not possible. RDDs are just a sequence of transformations, the only thing you could possible mutate is the source data. (Or hack into the cache, but I wouldn't recommend that)

Answer (score 2):

The MapReduce programming model (and FP) doesn't really support updates of single values.  Rather one is supposed to define a sequence of transformations.

Now when you have interdependent values, i.e. you cannot perform your transformation with a simple `map` but need to aggregate multiple values and update based on that value, then what you need to do is think of a way of grouping those values together then transforming each group - or define a monoidal operation so that the operation can be distributed and chopped up into substeps.

**Group By Approach**

Now I'll try to be a little more specific for your particular case.  You say you have subtrees, is it possible to first map each node to an key that indicates the corresponding subtree?  If so you could do something like this:

`nodes.map(n => (getSubTreeKey(n), n)).grouByKey().map ...`

**Monoid**

(strictly speaking you want a commutative monoid) Best you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#Commutative_monoid

For example `+` is a monoidal operation because when one wishes to compute the sum of, say, an RDD of Ints then the underlying framework can chop up the data into chunks, perform the sum on each chunk, then sum up the resulting sums (possibly in more than just 2 steps too).  If you can find a monoid that will ultimately produce the same results you require from single updates, then you have a way to distribute your processing. E.g.

`nodes.reduce(_ myMonoid _)`