# I there a way to update a field in an apache-spark RDD?

Tags: hive, apache-spark

I know that RDD's are immutable but I wanted to know if there was a way we could update a field in the RDD based on some if conditions.

Help would be really appreciated.

Thank you,
Jo

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the efficient way to update value inside Spark's RDD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132271/what-is-the-efficient-way-to-update-value-inside-sparks-rdd)

Comment: You can `map` (with the `if` conditions) the `RDD` in such cases and use later the reference to the updated `RDD`.

Answer (score 0):

They are immutable, but because some sequences of oeprations can be pipelined (e.g., `map().flatMap().filter()...`) into a single *stage* (JVM task), it's pretty efficient. Allowing mutation would undermine correctness and probably performance since you would have to stream data again from through the processor to mutate it (speculation).