# How to insert or update spark rdd which is already loaded from external database

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a 100 000 records in mongodb. I have loaded a part of them in RDD and after a while when I get a new record which is matching with the data already loaded in RDD. I need to add the new record directly to RDD and not to external database.

Comment: First let us know, what are possible options you have tried and paste your code to know the scenario much more better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132271/what-is-the-efficient-way-to-update-value-inside-sparks-rdd

Comment: I have not tried anything uptill now. i have studied about indexed rdd but could not get exact content of it. Firstly I want to know whether it is possible or not.IF possible then how?? Regarding code I could not post it right now. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it mean , only one RDD will exist at any given time? Can anyone answer this question

Comment: If one of the answer provided answers your question please accept it to close the issue ! Review the answers please.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new `RDD` with the values you want to add, and use `RDD.union`. Something like:

```
var rdd: RDD[T] = ...

rdd = rdd.union(sc.makeRDD(Array[T](...)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spark, RDD is immutable. Once an RDD is created, it can't be changed any more.

From the [paper of RDD](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~matei/papers/2012/nsdi_spark.pdf):

> Formally, an RDD is a read-only, partitioned collection of records.
>   RDDs can only be created through deterministic operations on either
>   data in stable storage or other RDDs.

So if you want to insert a row into an RDD, the only way is to create a new RDD with the new row and datas in the old RDD.

============================= UPDATE =============================
**In case that you'd like to use IndexedRDD:**

1. Download the IndexedRDD packages in Spark Shell: 
   `usb/$ spark/bin/spark-shell --packages amplab:spark-indexedrdd:0.3 \
       --repositories https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ankurdave/maven-repo/master`
2. Import the IndexedRDD package: 
   `import edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.spark.indexedrdd.IndexedRDD
   import edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.spark.indexedrdd.IndexedRDD._`
3. Then you could cast your RDD like: 
   `val iRDD = IndexedRDD(rdd)`
4. And now you can insert or delete rows on the indexed RDD: 
   `iRDD.put(0L, "New Row")`

For more details please check [here](http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/6/exercises/indexedrdd.html)

Comment: But I have heard that by creating indexed RDD we can update that indexed RDD is it true??